# insert two icons in JTextpane

Tags: java

How can I add more then one image into a JTextPane?

I have the following code which appends only the first Image.

```
Image img = null;
Image img2 = null;

try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File(Main.imagePath + "1.jpg"));
    img2 = ImageIO.read(new File(Main.imagePath + "2.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Image simg = img.getScaledInstance(310, 90, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
Image simg2 = img2.getScaledInstance(310, 90, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

Main.ScreenText.insertIcon ( new ImageIcon(simg) );
Main.ScreenText.insertIcon ( new ImageIcon(simg2) );
```

The ScreenText is a JTextPane.

Comment: I tried this and it worked fine. The only potential cause I found for not being able to see the second image was when the container was too small and it was off-screen, maybe that's your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by putting the images into JLabels and setting the JTextpane to Box Layout:

```
Image img = null;
Image img2 = null;

try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File(Main.imagePath + "1.jpg"));
    img2 = ImageIO.read(new File(Main.imagePath + "2.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Image simg = img.getScaledInstance(310, 90, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
Image simg2 = img2.getScaledInstance(310, 90, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

JLabel simgLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(simg));
JLabel simgLabel2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(simg2));

Main.ScreenText.setLayout(new BoxLayout(Main.ScreenText, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
Main.ScreenText.insertComponent( simgLabel );
Main.ScreenText.insertComponent( simgLabel2 );
```